# Unable to download file in mobile, if I have b64 of file

Tags: meteor

I have b64 data of a file, I want to download that file in my mobile app made using meteor. Please tell how to do this.

Till now I am able to create blank file in my mobile but when I tried to write in file then it is writing either blob of that data or b64, I think this is not correct way.

So please tell how I can download file directly in mobile from b64 using meteor.

Comment: You have to share the code as well, so it would be possible to understand what and how you're trying to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I am using with this I am able to create blank file in mobile and it is writing blob data in file, but I want to have original file.

```
if (platform_device == 'Android') {            
  var file_name= result.filename;
  var file_data='data:application/octet-stream;base64,'+result.blobdata;
  window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalDataDirectory, function(dir) {
       dir.getFile(result.filename, { create: true }, function(file) {    
         file.createWriter(function (fileWriter)
          {
           fileWriter.onwriteend = function()
           {  
             var time = Date.now();
             console.log('Data saved.',time);  
           };
         fileWriter.onerror = function(e)
           {
            console.log('There was an error writing the data file.', e);
           };

        fileWriter.write(new Blob([result.blobdata], { type:'text/plain' }));
    });

       });
   });
 }
```